# Create record link using the HTTP API

Tags: surrealdb

Using SurrealDB, how can one create a record link by posting JSON using the HTTP API? The SurrealDB documentation describes how to do so using SurrealQL but does not have comments regarding the HTTP API.

Since JSON strings contain quotes, I am not sure how SurrealDB would differente between a regular string property of a JSON object, and a record id of the form `personTable:myid`.